# Where do I put this function in my code? jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

Okay, so for class I have to make a CRUD application basically. I have to have a nav bar that links to different "pages" that are loaded in using a server.js file. In that server is where I load a JSON file that holds two arrays, one for pages, or sections, and another for users. The goal is to input information about a user in one section, hit a button and then that user's info will be listed in a different section. You also need to be able to delete each individual user at will, and it's all local.

My problem is that I have this addUser function, and within this function there's a click listener for the add button. Right now, the only thing it does when it's supposed to be clicked it throws a console.log, but I can't get that to work. The addUser function also has a console.log that's running fine, and I believe that my problem is that I don't know where I'm supposed to be adding the addUser function into my code. Just to be safe, I'll go ahead and list all my code. First is the server.js:

```
 var SERVER = (function(){
    //variable to store data.users into
    var _userData = [];
    var _sectionData = [];

    //getting the data and putting it into the variables above
    var _loadData = function(){
        $.getJSON("./data/data.json", function(data){
             _userData = data.Users;
             _sectionData = data.Sections;

             //console.log(_sectionData);
        })
    }

    var _showData = function(){
        return _userData;
    }

    var _getSection = function(sectionYouWant){
        let sec = {};
        $.each(_sectionData, function(idx, section){
            if(section.sectionName == sectionYouWant){
                sec = section.sectionContent;
            }
        });
        return sec;
    }

    _loadData();

    return {
        loadData: _loadData,
        showData: _showData,
        getSection: _getSection
    }
})()
```

next is the app.js

```
    function addUser(){
    console.log("firing addUser");

    $('#addButton').click(function(e){
        console.log("are you working????")
        e.preventDefault();
    })
}

function initNavListeners(){
    $("#home").click(function(e){
        //console.log('click home');
        var sectionData = SERVER.getSection('home');
        $('.wrapper').html(sectionData);
    });

    $("#view").click(function(){
        //console.log('click view users');
        var userData = SERVER.showData();
        var sectionData = SERVER.getSection('view');

        $(".wrapper").html(sectionData);

        function showUsers(){
            $.each(userData, function(idx, user){
                $(".wrapper").append(`
                <br/><p><b>Name:</b> ${user.fName} ${user.lName}</p>

                <p><b>Email Address:</b>
                ${user.email}</p>

                <p><b>Twitter Handle:</b>
                ${user.twitter}</p>

                <button class="delete" id=${idx}>DELETE</button><br/>`)
            })
        }

        showUsers();

    });

    $("#register").click(function(e){
        //console.log('click register');
        addUser();
        var sectionData = SERVER.getSection('register');
        $('.wrapper').html(sectionData);
    });
}

$(document).ready(function(){
    SERVER.loadData();
    initNavListeners();

    var sectionData = SERVER.getSection('home');
    $('.wrapper').html(sectionData);
})
```

Finally, the JSON:

```
    {
    "Users": [
        {
            "fName": "Andrea",
            "lName": "Trigg",
            "email": "at@users.com",
            "twitter": "@at"
        }
    ],
    "Sections": [
        {
            "sectionName": "home",
            "sectionContent": "<h1>HOME</h1><p>Welcome to the home page for my Homework 5 assignment! In this little application, you can register users and it will be submitted to a local JSON file. Then when you go to the view users page, it will show all the current users registered. You can also delete each individual user by pressing the \"delete user\" button below their information.</p><p>I hope this will work on your machine because it definitely works on mine!</p><p>I'm honestly not sure what else I should put here, so have a gif of a cute kitten trying to eat their own tail.</p><img src=\"https://i.pinimg.com/originals/84/c8/ba/84c8bab01787f2ee1ebef1378e9e8444.gif\"><p>I hope you have a great week! Thank you for taking a look at my Homework 5!</p>"
        },
        {
            "sectionName": "view",
            "sectionContent": "<h1>VIEW USERS</h1><p>Scroll below to see all users stored in the database. Click the delete button to delete a user from the database (careful, you won't get the information back if you delete!)</p>"
        },
        {
            "sectionName": "register",
            "sectionContent": "<h1>REGISTER</h1><p>Register a new user by using the form below!</p><form><input id=\"first\" type=\"text\" value=\"\" placeholder=\"First Name:\"><br/><input id=\"last\" type=\"text\" value=\"\" placeholder=\"Last Name:\"><br/><input id=\"emailAddress\" type=\"text\" value=\"\" placeholder=\"Email:\"><br/><input id=\"twitterHandle\" type=\"text\" value=\"\" placeholder=\"Twitter Handle\"><br/><input id=\"addButton\" type=\"button\" value=\"SUBMIT\"></form>"
        }
    ]
}
```

If you see anything that could be causing my click listener to not be working while the function itself is, that would be a tremendous help. I'm really struggling with this so any help would be great! Thank you!

Comment: I haven't had time to work through all the logic, but you're adding that event listener in the `addUser` function - which appears only to be called when the register button is clicked. So assuming you haven't clicked "register" yet, this is why the add button isn't working. And adding an event listener inside another event handler is almost always an antipattern - you can end up with loads of identical handlers for the same event, which basically always causes problems. With very rare exceptions, event listeners should be created once, on page load or when an element is created.

Answer (score 0):

Wow okay so after working on this for three hours, I finally figured it out.

So basically, you take the addUser function and instead of having it be global, you put it into the #register click listener that's in the initNavListener. It should look something like this:

```
$("#register").click(function(e){
        //initListeners();
        //console.log('click register');
        var userData = SERVER.showData();
        var sectionData = SERVER.getSection('register');
        $('.wrapper').html(sectionData);

        function addUser(){
            console.log("firing addUser");

            $('#addButton').click(function(e){
                console.log("are you working????")
                e.preventDefault(); )}
```

I feel like the biggest idiot right now :'D

ETA: If anyone wants to help me figure out how to delete these users that would be cool, but it's not listed in the rubric as something that I need to do, so I'm not putting major emphasis on it atm.